# How to make basic game networking

Tags: c++, networking

I am using RakNet library, it is my first attemp to do anything with networking.
I have initialised everything and connected, but what now?

Should I send packet with new position whenever player presses key to a server and then from a server to other players?

This is what I have for now: (I think everything might be important here, so I don't see any way to shorten code for you)

```
#include "Main.h"

void Init();
void Logic();
void Render();
void Clear();

AllegroWrapper al;

RakNet::RakPeerInterface *peer = 0;
RakNet::Packet *packet = 0;
char str[512];
bool isServer;

const int maxPlayers = 2;
const int serverPort = 60000;

Bitmap *bmpPlayer = 0;
int playerID = 0;
bool readyToPlay = false;

class Player
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    bool alive;

    Player()
    {
        x = 100;
        y = 100;

        alive = false;
    }
};

Player player[2];

int main()
{
    Init();
    while( al.mainLoop )
    {
        Logic();

        if(al.doRender())
            Render();
    }
    Clear();
    return 0;
}

void Init()
{
    al.Init();

    peer = RakNet::RakPeerInterface::GetInstance();

    cout<<"Are we (0)Server, or (1)Client?\n";
    int buf;
    cin>>buf;
    if( buf == 0 )
    {
        RakNet::SocketDescriptor sd(serverPort, 0);
        peer->Startup(maxPlayers, &sd, 1);
        isServer = true;

        cout<<"\nStarting a server...\n";
        peer->SetMaximumIncomingConnections(maxPlayers);
    }
    else
    {
        RakNet::SocketDescriptor sd;
        peer->Startup(1, &sd, 1);
        isServer = false;

        cout<<"\nStarting a client...\n";
        peer->Connect("127.0.0.1", serverPort, 0, 0);
    }

    bmpPlayer = al_load_bitmap("player.png");
}

void Logic()
{
    al.Logic();

    /*if(al.ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        al.mainLoop = false;*/

    for(packet = peer->Receive(); packet; peer->DeallocatePacket(packet), packet = peer->Receive())
    {
        switch(packet->data[0])
        {
        case ID_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION:
            {
                cout<<"A connection is incoming.\n";
            } break;

        case ID_NO_FREE_INCOMING_CONNECTIONS:
            {
                cout<<"The server is full.\n";
            } break;

        case ID_REMOTE_NEW_INCOMING_CONNECTION:
            {
                cout<<"Another client has connected.\n";
            } break;

        case ID_CONNECTION_REQUEST_ACCEPTED:
            {
                cout<<"Our connection request has been accepted.\n";
                player[playerID].alive = true;
                readyToPlay = true;
            } break;

        case ID_CONNECTION_LOST:
            {
                if (isServer)
                {
                    cout<<"A client lost the connection.\n";
                }else 
                {
                    cout<<"Connection lost.\n";
                }
            } break;

        case ID_REMOTE_CONNECTION_LOST:
            {
                cout<<"Another client has lost the connection.\n";
            } break;

        case ID_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
            {
                if (isServer)
                {
                    cout<<"A client has disconnected.\n";
                }else 
                {
                    cout<<"We have been disconnected.\n";
                }
            } break;

        case ID_REMOTE_DISCONNECTION_NOTIFICATION:
            {
                cout<<"Another client has disconnected.\n";
            } break;

        default:
            {
                cout<<"Message with identifier " << packet->data[0] << " has arrived.\n";
            } break;
        }
    }

    if( isServer == false && readyToPlay == true )
    {
        if(al.ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN) 
        {
            switch(al.ev.keyboard.keycode) 
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_D:
                {
                    player[playerID].x += 5;

                }
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Render()
{
    al.ClearToColor(al.SetRGB(0,0,200));

    //if( isServer == false )
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++)
        {
            if( player[i].alive == true )
            {
                al_draw_bitmap(bmpPlayer, player[i].x, player[i].y, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    al.FlipDisplay();
}

void Clear()
{
    al.Clear();
    RakNet::RakPeerInterface::DestroyInstance(peer);
}
```